# ASP.NET converting HTML to PDF

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, pdf

I have tried multiple plugins and c# classes to try and convert the HTML and CSS on my asp.net project to a pdf and even though the code used looks fine, and the button click works for other functions, I just cannot seem to get any html to pdf function to work.  Has anyone else encountered this, or know if there is something I have missed to resolve it?

This is the latest code I have tried for hiqpdf in C#:

```
protected void Print_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    HtmlToPdf htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdf();

    // set PDF page size, orientation and margins
    htmlToPdfConverter.Document.PageSize = PdfPageSize.A4;
    htmlToPdfConverter.Document.PageOrientation = PdfPageOrientation.Portrait;
    htmlToPdfConverter.Document.Margins = new PdfMargins(0);

    // convert HTML to PDF 
    htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertUrlToFile("http://localhost:51091/Printout","mcn.pdf");


}
```

Comment: What does it mean it doesn't work? Errors? Please be more specific.

Comment: Hi @SamiKuhmonen, nothing happens when I run the code

Answer (score 0):

It is not stated directly within theHiQpdf documentation of the method, but the method `ConvertUrlToFile()` stores the produced pdf file locally on the disc. On some example page (Convert URLs and HTML Code to PDF) the following comment can be found:

```
        // ConvertUrlToFile() is called to convert the html document and save the resulted PDF into a file on disk
        // Alternatively, ConvertUrlToMemory() can be called to save the resulted PDF in a buffer in memory
        htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertUrlToFile(url, pdfFile);
```

Since your example shows a button-click eventhandler, the file is probably generated but not used to return in the http response. You have to write the data into the response. The methods `ConvertToStream()` or `ConvertToMemory` should come in handy to do so. Don't forget to use `Response.Clear()` or `Response.ClearContent()` and `Response.ClearHeader()` before that and `Flush() and Close()` afterwards.